# kind of insect or kind of insects?

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural, plural-forms

Should *insect* in the following sentence be in a plural form?

> It is a dragonfly. It is a kind of insect (or insect**s**?).

Shouldn't we always use plural noun after *a type/kind of* ?